# How to save scope to an image file without using plot?

Tags: matlab, simulink

This condition is very important, because plot stretches my graph in an unacceptable manner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this one, it's too hard to figure out what the question is.

Comment: If I can try to interpret, do you mean you want to save the image shown in the Scope block, rather than using plot at the command line using saved data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the comment by MikeT is correct, and you are trying to save the image shown in a Scope block, there are a couple of ways you could do this:

- [Print the contents of the scope window](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/scope.html#f8-1272092) by clicking the **Print** icon, the leftmost icon on the Scope toolbar. Then choose to print to a file instead of to a printer.
- [Create an editable figure from a scope block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/scope.html#bqw_i7z) using the [SIMPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/simplot.html) function. This will create a figure that looks like the display on the screen of a Scope block, then you can [save the figure to a file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f3-124745.html#f3-125860) using the figure window's **File** menu or the functions [SAVEAS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html) or [PRINT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used "saveas" method, it works but, it has a problem with stepped function. When it's ploted in scope I see straight vertical lines, but when it's ploted by plot method, there is lines, but at an angle.

Comment: @kspacja: My guess is that there is a slight difference in how the scope block displays step-like data. For example, let's say you have 3 data points, with a step at the second point. The scope block may be similar to plotting `plot([1 2 2 3],[0 0 1 1]);`, whereas the result of SIMPLOT may be similar to plotting `plot([1 2 3],[0 0 1])`. Notice how the first plot replicates point 2 for the x data (with a 0 and 1 for the y data), which makes a vertical line. The second plot would instead have a line joining point (2,0) to point (3,1).

Answer (score 3):

As the answer of gnovice is outdated (at least since R2013), and the new builtin function is rather inconvenient to use, I'd like to suggest my little script.

```
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','On')
set(gcf,'Units','centimeters','PaperUnits','centimeters')
pos = get(gcf,'Position');
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0 0 pos(3) pos(4)],'Papersize',[ pos(3),pos(4) ]);
set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off','Renderer','painters')
saveas(gcf,'scope.pdf')
```

Which gives you a vector graphic in exactly the same size and look, like the last opened scope window. Of course you can modify additional properties and also print it as jpeg with a certain resolution. But then you should rather use `print`:

```
...
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer')
print(gcf,'scope.jpg','-djpeg','-r600')
```

results into a 600dpi Jpeg file.
The units doesn't really matter, as long as they are consistent between figure and paper.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to choose `File - Print to Figure` inside the scope. Then a Figure opens that you can save as `.fig`.